# What does three dots mean in C language function

Tags: c, linux, function, syntax

I'm trying to understand `libv4l2`, & came across with following [function](https://github.com/philips/libv4l/blob/master/libv4l2/libv4l2.c#L744) that contains three dots in the argument part. What does this ... mean?

```c
int v4l2_ioctl (int fd, unsigned long int request, ...)
{
  void *arg;
  va_list ap;
  int result, index, saved_err;
  int is_capture_request = 0, stream_needs_locking = 0;
```

Also, my C knowledge is poor. So please, *Explain Like I’m 5*

---

I'm expecting to understand that does `...` meant in a function,
I've done basic search about these three-dots, but only found something related with C's Macro (not good results with something related with C functions).
My long-term goal is to understand about this `v4l2-ioctl` function, (not like understand in and out) but understand briefly so I can use this `v4l2-ioctl` comfortably.

Comment: Actually it is, Sorry I didn't know the term/lingo, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a variadic function- a function that can take a variable number of arguments

you have to access them with va_start, va_arg and va_end

if u want to read more about it u can here:

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html